# aggregate several computations into one in Ember.computed

Tags: ember.js

Let us assume, I have several computed properties in my Controller which alters the model:

```
  _parents: Ember.computed.mapBy('model', 'parent'),
  _parentUniq: Ember.computed.uniq('_parents'),
  parents: Ember.computed.map('_parentUniq', (rawParent)=> {
return `\parent\${rawParent}`
  }),
  sortedParents:Ember.computed('parents',function(){
    return this.get('parents').sort();
  }),
```

In my template I use only `sortedParents`. Can I chain Ember.computed somehow?

Comment: It should work. I did it several times in components. [An example](https://github.com/tubitak-bilgem-yte/ember-contextual-table/blob/master/addon/components/data-table.js#L14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ember-composable-helpers` addon. you can chain multiple helpers . [reference](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers)
Sample format,

`(sort-by "age:desc" (map (action "appendParent") (union (map-by 'parent' model))))`

include the below function in `actions`,

```
appendParent(rawParent){
 `\parent\${rawParent}`
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
In case of array of just string or number, then you should provide sorter function to sort,

```
{{sort-by mySorter result}}
```

and define `mySorter` function in controller,

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    result: ['a', 'c', 'b'],
    mySorter(a, b) {
        if (a > b) {
            return 1;
        } else if (a < b) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice approach!

and in case of Array, what should I put instead of "age:desc" in sort-by?

Comment: @chilicoder I updated answers, I assume your array contains string or numbers, so you need to provide sorter functions to deal. [reference](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers/pull/151/files)

Comment: @kumkanilam I tried to find out is it possible to provide nothing or some shortcut to have the same behaviour as in [1,2,3,4].sort(); function.. but apparently it is not possible due to the code. 

I accepted your answer, I liked the approach. Thank you!